# My on-board Sound card is not working after installing video card

Tags: windows-8, audio, graphics-card, sound-card, nvidia-geforce

There are two problems after installing a new graphics card on my pc. I installed a NVIDIA Gforce GT 610 1gb graphic card. It disabled my built in sound card.

1. There is no Playback audio device showning on my sound option.
2. It also disabled my Recording device and it is not detecting any input or an output headphones.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the drivers for your old sound card?

Comment: Yes i tried 2 times and restart my PC but there is no sign of recover

Comment: To confirm you should completely uninstall and remove your sound card drivers, reboot your computer, and reinstall the sound card drivers.

Comment: As an aid to troubleshooting, does removing the graphics card restore the sound card?  What type of sound card is this? Is it an integrated audio device or a dedicated soundcard?

Comment: Is this a graphics card with "build in HDMI sound" ?

Comment: Yes my new graphi card have a HDMI port

Comment: @Mokubai my pc have a built-in audio card with built-in speaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I install my card, it automatically disables my built-in sound from BIOS setup. Just restart the PC, go to BIOS setup, and enable on-board sound card. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue right click on my computer and click on device manager.

If not search for the device manager in windows 8.1 and check and see if there is any missing driver or it is disabled. enable that if it is enabled do check for the  for the latest driver update.

please let us know which audio chipset you have on your MOBO.

to do that install a tool by the name speccy this will only work if you have the driver installed.
https://www.piriform.com/speccy

to update the driver you could you the software iobit driver booster not much reliable to all but you could give it a shot

http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php

please comment if it works for